AWS Amplify Authenticator: Close login dialog on sign out
I've implemented the login process with the "aws-amplify/ui-react" library like the following:
Login component
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { withAuthenticator, Button } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

export default function Login() {

  return (
    <Authenticator>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user?.username}</h1>
          <Button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</Button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );

}

In the App class, I used the component Login :
showHome() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showLogin: false
    }));
}

showLogin() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showLogin: true
    }));
}


<Nav.Link href="#top" id="signin" className="btn btn-warning ms-3 nav-link" type="button"
 onClick={this.showLogin}>{this.labelLogin()}</Nav.Link>
{ this.state.showLogin &&
     <Login signOut={this.showHome} label={"Logout"} />
}

When I click the Login button, it works fine showing the Login dialog, then after the login it shows the Logout button.
The problem is: when clicking the logout button, it still shows the Login dialog, without calling the "showHome" function.
I also tried to call the function signOut instaed of showHome, with no success:
signOut() {
    try {
      Amplify.signOut();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing out: ', error);
    }
}

Any idea to how to hide the login dialog on logout?
Thanks

I solved using the "aws-amplify/auth" library as the following, in the Login component:
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import { signOut } from "aws-amplify/auth"
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

import awsconfig from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

function Login( { doSignOut, label } ) {
  async function handleSignOut() {
    await signOut();
    await doSignOut();
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleSignOut}>
      {label}
    </button>
  )
}

export default withAuthenticator(Login);

And passing the method to hide the Login in the App class:
<Login doSignOut={this.showHome} label={"Logout"} />

